# Convert Set with specific Type to Array - Swift 2.3

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, core-data, set

Using `Swift 2.3`, I have a `Core Data` `Set` defined with a specific type, like this :

```
@NSManaged public var personEntities: Set<PersonEntity>?
```

And I simply want to convert that to a swift 2.3 `Array` of `PersonEntity` - simple right?  Ive tried the following and they all produce errors of various kinds :

```
cell.people = Array(self.memory.personEntities)
```

(Cannot invoke initializer for type .. with an argument list of type ..)

```
cell.people = self.memory.personEntities.flatMap({$0 as? PersonEntity})!
```

(Cannot assign value of type Person Entity to type [PersonEntity])

```
cell.people = self.memory.personEntities.flatMap({$0})
```

(Flatmap produces U, not the contextual result type _)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: That's because `personEntities` is an optional. Does it has to be an optional? It could very well have the default value of `[]`, being an empty `Set`.

Comment: @Eendje Assuming that `nil` == `[]` is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: @LukeSmith YOu'll have to unwrap your optional `Set<PersonEntity>?` to get a `Set<PersonEntity>`. From there you can pass it into the `Array` initializer.

Comment: @Alexander hence I'm asking if it should be an optional. Would make things easier in his case if it doesn't matter if it's `nil` or `[]`.

Comment: @Eendje You shouldn't pick between the two based on programmatic convenience. They have two very different semantics

Comment: Hey thanks.  Its only optional because thats the way the Core Data managed object subclass was created, so I assumed it had to be that way (so core data object can be empty)

Comment: @Alexander I totally agree with you, but exactly because of Luke's latest comment, I was asking it.

Comment: So assuming I have to leave it optional, I must first unwrap it right?  So Im going to end up with a few lines of code here, rather than a nice single line 'flatmap' type thing

Comment: @LukeSmith: It depends on what you want. `Array(personEntities ?? [])` defaults it to an empty array (as suggested above), `personEntities.flatMap(Array.init)` makes it an optional array.

Comment: And btw, please copy/paste complete, unabridged error messages.

Comment: @MartinR option 1 works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks for contributers via comments, this was the correct answer :

```
cell.people = Array(self.memory.personEntities ?? [])
```

It failed previously because `self.memory.personEntities` is an `Optional`.  So by adding `?? []` it could fail to get `personEntities` (if its nil) and instead just provide an empty array `[]`.